# Value Error: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'favicon.ico

Tags: django

I am getting this error every time I execute an action on my application. Although it is not a fatal error I am sure it does effect the working of my program. Below is the traceback of the error. Can somebody that understands this please help.

```
[04/Jan/2021 07:13:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6081
```

[04/Jan/2021 07:13:14] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields_*init*_.py", line
1774, in get_prep_value
return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'favicon.ico'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 4
7, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, i
n _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in
 view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in
 dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line 106,
 in get
    self.object = self.get_object()
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line 36,
in get_object
    queryset = queryset.filter(pk=pk)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 942, in f
ilter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 962, in _
filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 969, in _
filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1358,
 in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1377,
 in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1319,
 in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1165,
 in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 24, in
__init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 76, in
get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line
 1776, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'favicon.ico'.
[04/Jan/2021 07:13:15] "GET /favicon.ico/ HTTP/1.1" 500 138569
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from.import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from accounts.views import (
    registration_view,
    account_view,
    login_view,
)
from .views import *
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'accounting/', include('accounting.urls')),
    url(r'cashflow/', include('cashflow.urls')),
    url(r'company/', include('company.urls')),
    url(r'^$', views.homepage, name="home"),
    url(r'about/$', views.about),
    path('register/', registration_view, name="register"),
    path('account/', account_view, name="account"),
    path(r'^login/$',login_view, name="login"),
    path('password_change/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_change_done.html'),
         name='password_change_done'),
    path('password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_change.html'),
         name='password_change'),
    path('password_reset/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_done.html'),
         name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    path('reset/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_complete.html'),
         name='password_reset_complete'),
    path('ex2', Ex2View.as_view(), name='ex2'),
    path('<pk>/', Ledger_accountView.as_view(), name='ledger_account-detail'),
    path('add', AddGeneralLedgerView.as_view(), name='add'),
    path('<pk>/edit', Ledger_accountEditView.as_view(), name='ledger_account-edit'),]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Can you post  `urls.py` content?

Comment: I added the main urls.py.

Comment: why are you trying to get  /favicon.ico, your favicon has wrong URL in template/frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your django template file. It might be missing the `static` tag for favicon.

```
<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'images/favicons/favicon.ico' %}">
```